# Transformation of data in mixed models (lme4)

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, data-transformation, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to fit the following model where I'm measuring fungal growth (length) in Petri dishes that were kept at 0C, room temperature, and 50C (Treatment).

> ```
> myModel <- lmer(Length ~ Treatment + Chemical_1 + Chemical_2 + 
> (1 | Treatment), data = myData, REML = F)
> ```

Each treatment has 60 Petri dishes. I quantified two chemicals in the media before fungal inoculations, and now I am determining if any of the chemicals in any of the treatments is playing a role in influencing fungal growth. All my variables (response and fixed effects) are NOT normally distributed and I have been reading about the different options available to deal with the situation, however; the more I read the more I get myself confused!!

Any idea what's the right way to move forward?

Comment: Why do you want to put a random effect per Treatment group? Do you expect that length measurements of Petri dishes within the same treatment are correlated? Mixed models are typically use to account for correlations you expect to have in your data.

Comment: the random effect represents the fact that the Petri dishes in each treatment (0C, room Temp. and 50C) were randomly selected. I don't expect that the length measurements in each treatment will be correlated.

Comment: Then I’d say you don’t need to put treatment as random effect. As said in my previous comment, by putting a random effect per treatment you assume that length measurements are correlated within each treatment group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

First of all, multilevel models do *not* assume that the variables are normally distributed.  They assume the errors are normally distributed. We don't know the error, but we estimate it by the residual.

Second, if it does turn out that your residuals are not normally distributed, what to do next depends. Your DV is length. If you take the log of length, then your model will have effects that change length multiplicatively rather than additively. That is a 1 unit change in an IV will lead to multiplying the expected value of the DV by a constant. Does that make sense? If it does, try log(length). If it doesn't, then maybe you need a nonlinear multilevel model.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I checked the errors for normality and it does seem to be normally distributed. Is there any specific test that I can perform to formally confirm the normality?